# Crash notifications from node.js app hosted on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a node.js server running on an Azure app service. I would like to receive an automated email notification in the event that the node app crashes.  I've been Googling and there seem to be so many options around monitoring provided by Azure, that it's quite overwhelming.  I looked at Azure Application Insights, but couldn't see the functionality I'm after + it seems expensive.

Is there a simple Azure approach for monitoring node.js app crashes, or a free third party solution which would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for receiving an email notification when your node.js app crashes or when returning Http 5XX status code, You can use [azure monitor alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-new-alert-rule?tabs=metric) and then [setting email notification in the action group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/action-groups).

Go to your Azure portal and navigate to your app service's page> under **Monitoring** click on **Alerts** blade> **create new alert rule** and add condition> **Select signal type** Http Server Errors.

[image]

Now set **Thresholds** as required> then under **"Actions"**, click on the "Add action group" button and create a new action group that includes your email address as a notification receiver> **Save** the alert rule.

Then go your action group's page and click on the "**Add action**" button and select "**Email/SMS/Push/Voice"** as the action type> add email address details> **Save** the action group.

Additionally you may also refer to this document for setting threshold and understanding metrics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor